# Error :- php is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: php, path, environment

So this is my path I have:

**`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3`**

And my php.exe file is in that folder...
I have tried to put:

**`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3;`**

**`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe`**

**`C:\wamp\bin\php`**

**`C:\wamp\bin\php;`**

But none of is not working.
I have no idea why its not working...
Thanks

Comment: Did you add that folder to your PATH?

Comment: What happens if you call C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php

Comment: I added a new variable called php with the path: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\    @Passkit, I tried and it didnt work.

Comment: Then it sounds like php.exe is not in that folder!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

PHP is not included in your PATH.
Right click your My Computer, then Properties, Advanced System Settings, Environment Variables and then find PATH variable, add your PHP installation dir there. Close your previously launched CMDs, re-launch it, it should work now.

Comment: I added a new variable called php with the path: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\

Comment: No, double click PATH variable, then go to end of the line, insert ; (semi-colon) then paste C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3

Comment: I tried did that also and still no luck... This is what it just before i paste, SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3

Comment: 1) Close your CMDs, re-launch them. 2) Go to C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3 folder, check if you find php.exe there. If not, try to locate php.exe file first, and put that path, not C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3

Comment: I can find the php.exe file inside the C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3 folder...

Comment: did you tried to close and re-launch cmd windows? I mean command prompt windows.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22218/discussion-between-user1049769-and-vahid-farahmand)